# Argparse optional positional arguments?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script which is meant to be used like this:

```bash
usage: installer.py dir [-h] [-v]
```

`dir` is a positional argument which is defined like this:

```
parser.add_argument('dir', default=os.getcwd())
```

I want the `dir` to be optional: when it's not specified it should just be `cwd`.

Unfortunately, when I don't specify the `dir` argument, I get `Error: Too few arguments`.

Answer (score 1168, accepted):

Use [`nargs='?'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) (or `nargs='*'` if you need more than one dir)

```
parser.add_argument('dir', nargs='?', default=os.getcwd())
```

extended example:

```
>>> import os, argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-v', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['-v'], dest='v', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('dir', nargs='?', default=os.getcwd())
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='dir', nargs='?', const=None, default='/home/vinay', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args('somedir -v'.split())
Namespace(dir='somedir', v=True)
>>> parser.parse_args('-v'.split())
Namespace(dir='/home/vinay', v=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(''.split())
Namespace(dir='/home/vinay', v=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['somedir'])
Namespace(dir='somedir', v=False)
>>> parser.parse_args('somedir -h -v'.split())
usage: [-h] [-v] [dir]

positional arguments:
  dir

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -v
```

Comment: Do the `?` and `*` mean the same thing they mean in regular expressions (i.e. `?` requires 0 or 1, and `*` requiring 0 or more)? If so, does `+` work as well?

Comment: @dolan: Yes, `+` works, too. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs for the details.

Comment: is there some way to get dir to show up in optional arguments?  or it seems that positional arguments should have a preceeding 'optional' qualifier.  is it possible to register (as far as help is concerned) it as such?

Comment: @ant From the above, you can see that dir is optional (that it appears in square brackets in argparse output indicates this).

Comment: Tx! Access dir from `options.dir`, not `args.dir`, as I was trying!

Comment: Here's the updated (Python 3) documentation--a careful reading of it explains it all: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs. For anyone new to the `argparse` module, start with the tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: @dolan and Vinay, '+' does not work because it requires at least one argument at the command line.

Answer (score 100):

As an extension to @VinaySajip answer. [There are additional `nargs` worth mentioning](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs).

1. `parser.add_argument('dir', nargs=1, default=os.getcwd())`

N (an integer). N arguments from the command line will be gathered together into a list

2. `parser.add_argument('dir', nargs='*', default=os.getcwd())`

'*'. All command-line arguments present are gathered into a list. **Note** that it generally doesn't make much sense to have more than one positional argument with `nargs='*'`, but multiple optional arguments with `nargs='*'` is possible.

3. `parser.add_argument('dir', nargs='+', default=os.getcwd())`

'+'. Just like '*', all command-line args present are gathered into a list. Additionally, an error message will be generated if there wasn’t at least one command-line argument present.

4. `parser.add_argument('dir', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER, default=os.getcwd())`

`argparse.REMAINDER`. All the remaining command-line arguments are gathered into a list. This is commonly useful for command line utilities that dispatch to other command line utilities

If the `nargs` keyword argument is not provided, the number of arguments consumed is determined by the action. Generally this means a single command-line argument will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced.

**Edit (copied from a comment by @Acumenus)** `nargs='?'` [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) say: '?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced.

Comment: It should be noted however that `nargs='?'` does not produce a list.

Comment: @A-B-B Last line of the answer `Generally this means a single command-line argument will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced.` Hope this helps...

Comment: The quoted line refers to the case of not defining `nargs`, but `nargs='?'` is defining it. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) say: _'?'. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced._

Comment: @A-B-B Just edit the answer if you feel that something is missing. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` and `nargs='*'`, as it seems to me, they are identical in their effect (tested in Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.6.1)?

Comment: note also that `default` is *required* to make this work. without specifying a default value, executing the parsing command without a value in that position will complain that a value is required for that argument.

Answer (score 24):

### Short Answer

As already shown in the previous two answers, you can accept an optional positional argument with `nargs='?'`. You could also turn the argument directly into a `Path` type and/or shorten the cwd to `.` if you wanted to:

**myfile.py**

```py
import argparse
import pathlib

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("dir", nargs="?", default=".", type=pathlib.Path)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

print("Installing to", parsed_args.dir.resolve())
```

```bash
$ python myfile.py
Installing to /users/myname/myfolder

$ python myfile.py /usr/bin/
Installing to /usr/bin
```

### Longer answer

Since you also mention the flag-style True/False options `-h` and `-v` in your question, these examples may be of use:

#### Flags (e.g. `-v`)

We might refer to optional options that take no arguments as "flags". With flags, we only care about whether they are given or not. `-h` is a flag that argparse adds automatically (along with the longer version `--help`) so we shouldn't really override that. If we consider `-v` then,

**myfile.py**

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        "-v",
        "--version",
        action="store_true")
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

if parsed_args.version:
    print("version flag given")
else:
    print("version flag not given")
```

Note that the second argument to `add_argument()` is a longer name for the option. It is not mandatory but it does make your subsequent code more readable (`parsed_args.version` vs `parsed_args.v`) and makes calls to your installer more explicit.

```bash
$ python myfile.py -v
version flag given

$ python myfile.py --version
version flag given

$ python myfile.py
version flag not given
```

#### Optional arguments (e.g. `--installdir /usr/bin/`)

One could argue that, in your case, you would be better off with an optional argument rather than a positional one.

**myfile.py**

```py
import argparse
import pathlib

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        "-i",
        "--installdir",  # Optional (but recommended) long version
        type=pathlib.Path,
        default="/bin"
        )
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

print("Installing to", parsed_args.installdir)
```

```bash
$ python myfile.py -i /usr/bin/
Installing to /usr/bin

$ python myfile.py --installdir /usr/bin/
Installing to /usr/bin

$ python myfile.py
Installing to /bin
```

Answer (score -12):

`parser.add_argument` also has a switch **required**. You can use `required=False`.
Here is a sample snippet with Python 2.7:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='get dir')
parser.add_argument('--dir', type=str, help='dir', default=os.getcwd(), required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: OP was asking about positional params, not '--dir'.  'required' is an invalid argument for positionals.  And 'false' was a typo, she meant 'False'.  +1 for newbie, -1 for sloppiness.

Comment: We can not use `required` for positional argument.