# changing the behaviour of argument having default value

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script that has a argument which has a default value.
I want to do something:

```
$sample.py => Dont do anything
$sample.py -R => Use default value of -R
$sample.py -R <value> =>do something based on value passed
```

Is this doable in argparse?

Hi all. Please note that my problem is different from the one mentioned in the solution.

Basically i want action corresponding to -R to be performed only when i pass -R on command line.
If only -R is passed then value of -R is default value.

If i run the py file without -R then no action corresponding to -R should be done.

Comment: Yes. This is doable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argparse optional positional arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments)

Comment: This looks like an optional optional argument, not a positional. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
parser.add_argument('-R',nargs='?', default='default',const='const')
```

should produce

```
test.py => namspace(R='default')
test.py -R => namespace(R='const')
test.py -R value => namespace(R='value')
```

This is documented in https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs, subsection `nargs='?'`.

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue, took me a while to adjust as per code :)