# 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals in python command

Tags: python, import, arguments, argparse

I want to implement import feature with required and optional parameters, to run this in this way:

```
python manage.py import --mode archive
```

where `--mode` is required and `archive` also.

I'm using argparse library.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Import'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--mode',
            required=True,
        )
        parser.add_argument('archive',
            required=True,
            default=False,
            help='Make import archive events'
        )
```

But I recived error:

```
TypeError: 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals
```

Comment: `archive` is **already** required, because it is a positional argument.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480202/225798

Answer (score 73):

You created a positional argument (no `--` option in front of the name). Positional arguments are *always* required. You can't use `required=True` for such options, just drop the `required`. Drop the `default` too; a required argument can't have a default value (it would never be used anyway):

```
parser.add_argument('archive',
    help='Make import archive events'
)
```

If you meant for `archive` to be a command-line switch, use `--archive` instead.

Comment: Note that although they're always required, one can define them to be empty with `nargs`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4480075/333599 .

Comment: @Calimo: that would only work for the last positional argument, however. And in this case, the OP wanted the positional argument to be mandatory, not optional.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `--mode archive` is supposed to mean "mode is archive", in other words `archive` is the *value* of the `--mode` argument, not a separate argument. If it were, it would have to be `--archive` which is not what you want.

Just leave out the definition of `archive`.