# Python argparse - mandatory argument - either positional or optional

Tags: python, argparse

I want the user to be able to pass a mandatory argument to 'argparse', with either positional, or optional argument.

I.e.,
both following forms are valid:

```
my_prog arg
my_prog -m arg
```

I've seen [Argparse optional positional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments)

But the suggestions there make *both* form optional. I want that *one* of them will be mandatory.

Of course, I can add a manual checking after parsing that at least one of them has been set. But I got a hunch that there must be a better solution.

(And even with my manual approach, the 'help' section shows both of them as optional)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mutually exclusive group` mechanism can take a `required` parameter.  It also works with one `?` positional along with the optionals (flagged arguments).  (more than one '?' positional doesn't make sense).

As for the `help` display there are 2 default groups, `positonal` and `optional`.  So even if an `optional` (flagged) is set to `required` it is, by default, displayed in the `optional` group.  The `usage` line is a better guide as to whether an argument is required or not.  If you don't like the group labels in the help section, define your own argument groups.

```
In [146]: import argparse
In [147]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [148]: gp = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
In [149]: gp.add_argument('pos', nargs='?', default='foo');
In [150]: gp.add_argument('-f','--foo', default='bar');

In [151]: parser.parse_args('arg'.split())
Out[151]: Namespace(foo='bar', pos='arg')

In [152]: parser.parse_args('-f arg'.split())
Out[152]: Namespace(foo='arg', pos='foo')

In [153]: parser.parse_args('arg -f arg'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FOO] [pos]
ipython3: error: argument -f/--foo: not allowed with argument pos

In [154]: parser.parse_args(''.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FOO] [pos]
ipython3: error: one of the arguments pos -f/--foo is required


In [155]: parser.parse_args('-h'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FOO] [pos]

positional arguments:
  pos

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

Oops, usage isn't showing the `-f` and `pos` in a mutually exlusive group.  Sometimes that `usage` formatting is brittle.

Switching the order in which the arguments are defined gives a better usage

```
In [156]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [157]: gp = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
In [158]: gp.add_argument('-f','--foo', default='bar');
In [159]: gp.add_argument('pos', nargs='?', default='foo');
In [160]: 
In [160]: parser.parse_args('-h'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] (-f FOO | pos)

positional arguments:
  pos

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
```

With a user defined argument group:

```
In [165]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [166]: gp = parser.add_argument_group('Mutually exclusive')
In [167]: gpm = gp.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
In [168]: gpm.add_argument('-f','--foo', default='bar');
In [169]: gpm.add_argument('pos', nargs='?', default='foo');
In [170]: 
In [170]: parser.parse_args('-h'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] (-f FOO | pos)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit

Mutually exclusive:
  -f FOO, --foo FOO
  pos
```

This is the one exception to the general rule argument_groups and mutually_exclusive_groups aren't designed for nesting.

The m-x-group was not required, usage would use `[]`

```
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f FOO | pos]
```

Comment: Great. Just one caveat: these group definitions must be after all other regular arguments, otherwise it won't show the nice `(-f FOO | pos)` in the help

Comment: Yes, 2 things affect the `usage`.  Positionals are shown after optionals, and a group only shows up if its arguments match that order.  Correcting that brittleness will require a major rewrite of the usage formatter.