# How to differentiate between default value and user given value in argparse, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm using Python 3 argparse to get command-line arguments. I have an optional argument with a default value. When I read its value, is it possible to know if the user manually inputted the value or is it default one?

Earlier, I had designed as above. Now, I want to store preferences from previous usage. So, if a user didn't input any value to the optional argument, I want to take the value from previous usage (if any). So, I want to determine whether the value came as a default value or user given value.

**Edit 1**: I have multiple arguments like this. I know I can remove default value for the arguments and assign them programmatically later. I just want to know if there is a simpler solution to this

Comment: when it is supposed to be a default value, you should have less arguments than when the user has to provide one, yes? You can just check how many arguments you are provided, and wrap that in a conditional.

Comment: Thing is I have multiple such arguments. So, I want to know which ones were provided by user and for which ones, default value was picked up.

Comment: Presumably you know what those defaults are, so you can check whether the value is the same as the default.

Comment: There is a possibility that user might input the default value :P

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments seems helpful for you, but it's not really a duplicate so I'm not marking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if a user didn't input any value to the optional argument, I want to take the value from previous usage (if any). So, I want to determine whether the value came as a default value or user given value.

Then you don't want to supply a default value; make the parameter optional (e.g. [Argparse optional positional arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480075/argparse-optional-positional-arguments) ), and then explicitly check for its presence or absence in the resulting Namespace object and do the appropriate thing in your code logic - presumably, check for a value in previous usage and *then* supply a default as a last resort. (Think of default values as a shortcut logic to handle the absence of the value; you need more complicated logic, so better to replace that system than to try to work around it.)

Comment: The value will be absent from the Namespace only if `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`.

Answer (score 2):

The surest way of identifying whether the user has provided a value is to leave the default at the default `None`.  There's nothing the user can say that will produce the same thing.  Then after parsing all you need to do is:

```
if args.myval is None:
    # no user input, set my own special default
else:
    # user value
```

If you set the `default=argparse.SUPPRESS`, the attribute will be omitted from the `args` namespace.  But testing for that case it a bit more awkward.

```
args.myval
```

will raise an error, which you could catch.  Or you could use `hasattr(args, 'myval').  Or handle the missing key in`vars(args)`.

Internally `parse_args` maintains a list (`set` actually) of Actions that it has 'seen'.  That's used to test for required Actions.  But that isn't available to users.  If it were available, sophisticated users could perform a wider variety of co-occurrence tests.

```
In [28]: import argparse
In [29]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [30]: a1 = parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')
```

Test without a value:

```
In [31]: args = parser.parse_args([])
In [32]: args
Out[32]: Namespace(foo=None)         # foo is present
In [33]: args.foo is None
Out[33]: True
```

Change the default to `SUPPRESS`:

```
In [35]: a1.default = argparse.SUPPRESS
In [36]: args = parser.parse_args([])
In [37]: args
Out[37]: Namespace()          # foo is missing
In [38]: args.foo
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

We could put `args.foo` in a `try: except AttributeError` block.

```
In [39]: hasattr(args, 'foo')
Out[39]: False
```

Or dictionary testing for missing value

```
In [46]: vars(args)
Out[46]: {}
In [47]: vars(args).get('foo') is None
Out[47]: True
In [48]: 'foo' in vars(args)
Out[48]: False
```

A default is most useful when it provides a valid, useful value, and it saves you from extra testing after parsing.