# python argparse different value if arg is provided in command line or absent

Tags: python, argparse

I want to use python's `argparse` to config the parameters input from command line. The behaviours for parsing the arguments can be:

1. `None` if the name is absent from command line.
2. Defaults to a value if the name is provided but left empty.
3. To the provided value.

Example code can be:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-generate-config", metavar="-g", nargs="?")
```

Parsing it:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(["-g"])  # leave it empty/didn't provide value
Namespace(generate_config=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(["-g", "config.txt"])
Namespace(generate_config='config.txt')
>>> parser.parse_args([])  # absent in the command line
Namespace(generate_config=None)
```

So leave it empty or don't provide the argument in the command line, both values are `None`. How can I set different behaviours/values for these two situations?

Comment: When using '?', define the `default` and `const` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching [stackflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), setting [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) to `argparse.SUPPRESS` in `add_argument` is of great help, as inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795203/3003072).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-generate-config", metavar="-g", nargs="?", default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

So:

```
>>> args = parser.parse_args(["-g"])  # leave it empty/didn't provide value
>>> args
Namespace(generate_config=None)
>>> args = parser.parse_args([])  # the argument is empty
>>> args
Namespace()
>>> args = parser.parse_args(["-g", "parameters.txt"])
>>> args
Namespace(generate_config='parameters.txt')
```

Though not exactly as what I want, it still can be achieved by checking `"generate_config" in args` and `args.generate_config is None`.