# TypeError: 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals

Tags: python

I want to give optional arguments to my Python3 code. I am using `argparse`

```
def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Solution")
    parser.add_argument("size", help="sector size")
    parser.add_argument("name", help="Disk name", required = False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    sec_size = args.size
    if not args.name :
        print('Will carry only few sets of operations')
    else :
        name = args.name
```

It is giving error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythoncode.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "pythoncode.py", line 145, in main
    parser.add_argument("name", help="Disk name", required = False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1335, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_positional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1447, in _get_positional_kwargs
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: 'required' is an invalid argument for positionals
```

Could someone please point what am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Optional arguments start with `--`, e.g. `--name`. That's the convention for shell arguments.

Comment: @AlexHall Not quite. Those are *options*, but positional arguments can *also* be optional, especially when they represent paths.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480202/225798

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`required=False` can be used for only optional arguments. And for optional arguments you should use `--`

```
parser.add_argument("--name", help="Disk name", required = False)
```

When there is no `--` the python considers it as a positional argument. So the functional argument  required is invalid for positional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can make *optional positional* arguments with `nargs='?'` instead of `required=False`.

```
parser.add_argument("name", help="Disk name", nargs='?')
```