# Python argparse, handle either several positional arguments OR optional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')

parser.add_argument('-l', '--login', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('FILTER1')
parser.add_argument('FILTER2')
parser.add_argument('FILTER3')
```

I'd like "--login" to be mutually exclusive from FILTER1, FILTER2, FILTER3. Also, FILTER1, FILTER2, FILTER3 are all required when any of the 3 are mentioned.

So either:

```
cli FILTER1 FILTER2 FILTER3
```

OR

```
cli --login
```

Comment: One positional is allowed in a `mutually_exclusive_group`, but it must be optional, that is, have an `nargs` of "?" or "*".  And you should provide a `default` with it.  A flagged `--filter` with `nargs=3` is a simpler idea.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to do this with argparse is to make the filters into an optional argument followed by `nargs=3` in a mutually exclusive group with "login". Otherwise, you could do your own parsing and make each filter [an optional positional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4480075/4518341).

#### Filters as optional

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

meg = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
meg.add_argument('-l', '--login', action='store_true')
meg.add_argument('-f', '--filters', nargs=3, metavar=('FILTER1', 'FILTER2', 'FILTER3'))

for arg_string in '-l', '-f 1 2 3', '-l -f 4 5 6', '-f 8 9':
    args = arg_string.split()
    try:  # This try-block for demo
        ns = parser.parse_args(args)
    except SystemExit:
        pass
    else:
        print(ns)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Namespace(login=True, filters=None)

Namespace(login=False, filters=['1', '2', '3'])

usage: tmp.py [-h] [-l | -f FILTER1 FILTER2 FILTER3]
tmp.py: error: argument -f/--filters: not allowed with argument -l/--login

usage: tmp.py [-h] [-l | -f FILTER1 FILTER2 FILTER3]
tmp.py: error: argument -f/--filters: expected 3 arguments
```

#### Own parsing

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-l', '--login', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('FILTER1', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('FILTER2', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('FILTER3', nargs='?')

for arg_string in '-l', '1 2 3', '-l 4 5 6', '8 9':
    args = arg_string.split()
    ns = parser.parse_args(args)
    print(ns)
    try:  # This try-block for demo
        if ns.login and ns.FILTER1 is not None:
            parser.error("filters not allowed with argument -l/--login")
        elif not ns.login and any(a is None for a in [ns.FILTER1, ns.FILTER2, ns.FILTER3]):
            parser.error("Expected three filters")
    except SystemExit:
        pass
    print()
```

Output:

```
Namespace(login=True, FILTER1=None, FILTER2=None, FILTER3=None)

Namespace(login=False, FILTER1='1', FILTER2='2', FILTER3='3')

Namespace(login=True, FILTER1='4', FILTER2='5', FILTER3='6')
usage: tmp.py [-h] [-l] [FILTER1] [FILTER2] [FILTER3]
tmp.py: error: filters not allowed with argument -l/--login

Namespace(login=False, FILTER1='8', FILTER2='9', FILTER3=None)
usage: tmp.py [-h] [-l] [FILTER1] [FILTER2] [FILTER3]
tmp.py: error: Expected three filters
```

You should also document this behaviour since argparse won't do it for you. You might also want to change the `parser.usage`. This can be a pain, so that's why I recommend the first option personally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group`, but it requires you to use optional arguments.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group() 

group.add_argument('-l', '--login', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('-f', '--filter', nargs=3)
```

Pass `required=True` to `add_mutually_exclusive_group` if you want either `--login` or `--filter` to be required.