# How to specify para mutual exclusive groups (sets) of arguments in argparse? Or make optional positional parameter with any number of args

Tags: python, argparse

I want the following usege:

Usage 1: `my_launch.py --list-installed`
Usage 2: `my_launch.py [-a | -b | -c <arg_c>] <appname [args ...]>`

Is that possible to combine with argparse?

If the `--list-installed` is used, then there should not be any other arguments.
In another case, there is required appname, and then zero or more arguments.

I have read about subparser, but they are not appropriate for my case, because they require the command to start from defined word (a subcommand).

I thought I could just collect everything in namespace, and then do my own logic. But the problem is that I cannot make an appname with its parameters captured. In usage 2 it is mandatory, in usage 1 it is prohibited.

Is it possible to make appname to collect all args behind it (I do it like this: `parser.add_argument("appname", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)`), and at the same time make the whole appname optional?

I also read about mutually exclusive groups, but the term is ambiguous. Actually, they are not "groups", but a set from which only one can be used. But I wanted two actually groups, one group for usage 1, another group for usage 2. And make them mutually exclusive. That is why I used "para" in question.

Comment: Unbelievable. I have found a solution right after I posted the question, but made several hours research before :(. I can use `parser.add_argument("appname", default=None, nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)`. From here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4480202/7869636. I thoughe that you need to respecify `nargs`, while it has been already specifically specified.  
Still, maybe someone suggest the beautiful solution using the argparse's logic.

Comment: `a/b/c` can work as A `mutually_exclusive_group`. While you can have separate groups, they can't be nested.  REMAINDER` ('...') is like `*` but takes all the rest.  '--' may also be useful.  REMAINDER` is not currently documented because there are some problematic edge cases, but it is useable.

Comment: Why `argparse` cannot nest (para?) groups? It is the standard argument parser library, and I am surprised that it is incomplete. `--` is not applicable for my case. Thanks for mentioning the reason why it is not documented. I also was surprised about that.

Comment: I worked on a patch to handle nested groups (with all logical possibilities) years ago.  Setup wasn't a problem, performing the tests not too hard.  Formatting the usage required a big rewrite.  That and other group issues can be found the github repository.

Comment: I would be ok to just be able to use that logic. If it cant handle formatting the usage, I could write it manually. Just like I did in this question, I just wrote two separate usage lines. Maybe it is possible to combine them in one, but it is not really needed, because readability is better when they are separate.

Comment: MEXgroups are an error checking mechanism, they don't alter the parsing.  In many cases you can do your own checking after parsing - checking for `False` or `is None`; or just ignoring some arguments.  Code wise this kind of group is a relatively simple addition to the parser, and the implementation in the usage formatting is rather brittle.